# How to check function parameters in Go

Tags: java, validation, go, guava, preconditions

[Guava Preconditions](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) allow to check method parameters in Java easily.

```
public void doUsefulThings(Something s, int x, int position) {
    checkNotNull(s);
    checkArgument(x >= 0, "Argument was %s but expected nonnegative", x);
    checkElementIndex(position, someList.size());
    // ...
}
```

These check methods raise exceptions if the conditions are not met.

Go has no exceptions but indicates errors with return values. So I wonder how an idiomatic Go version of the above code would look like.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on context.

If `doUsefulThings` is a public function exported from a package, return an `error`. You can have exported package level `error` variables that you can return, and the caller can check if the returned `error` is equal to one of the documented ways to screw up.

If it's not exported, and it would be a programmer error to call it incorrectly, I think it's reasonable to `panic(errors.New("bla bla bla"))`. Although the function would panic once you dereferenced that pointer, anyway.

For this: `checkArgument(x >= 0, "Argument was %s but expected nonnegative", x)` you can pass in `uint`.

Comment: Panicing would be even okay in an exported function or method, especially if it is documented and possibly named MustXYZ see e.g. regexp.MustCompile (http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#MustCompile)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure using assertions to check basic properties of the parameters is in the philosophy of the language.

In case of a parameter which really could have an invalid value without bug (for example you don't find it in database), you would return an error :

```
func doUsefulThings(s *Something) error {
      // return an error if your algorithm detect an invalid value
```

Asserting that `s` isn't `nil` would only add verbosity. There is no point in verifying you weren't provided `nil`.

Adding a return parameter, especially `error` forces all users to check this error. Don't write code in your function to defend against trivial bugs in the caller code. The caller should simply test it's not `nil`, **if that's possible depending of the rest of the code**, before calling your function.

Comment: It doesn't add verbosity, it's proper way to do for functions which are externally exposed from the package.